# Bluesnap Extended API Error: “expected total price does not match BlueSnap calculated total”

Tags: payment, bluesnap

I am using Bluesnap’s Extended Payment API. Recently we get the following error when we are trying to charge a subscription: “expected total price does not match BlueSnap calculated total”. Has anyone had this issue before?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error is usually returned when the total cart price you pass into the API is not equal to what BlueSnap thinks it should be. Usually this is because BlueSnap identifies additional charges that need to be part of the shopping cart total, such as taxes. Are you on the reseller model with Bluesnap? If so, then Bluesnap will collect taxes in some states (CA and MA). Then you would need to include the taxes in your shopping cart total price.